# Aggregate Results after all router completes executing

Tags: mule

Is it possible to do some action once an all router has completed processing. The all router has 3 different subflows which are executed asynchronously. Once all the sub flows have completed executing. I need to execute logic to determine which has failed and which was successful. Should i implement an aggregator. Can someone provide an example.

```
<flow name="InvalidFlow2" doc:name="InvalidFlow2">
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="c:\filelanding\in4" pollingFrequency="100" connector-ref="input_4">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(?!.*Processed|.*Failed)(.*)" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Source_System" value="XXXX"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <!-- Test  Component causes a delay of 20 sec....-->
    <test:component waitTime="20000"></test:component>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>

    <all doc:name="All">
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <flow-ref name="TesterFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <flow-ref name="TesterFlow3" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <flow-ref name="TesterFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </async>
    </all>
    <flow-ref name="TesterFlow4" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        <!-- if any one fails remove the processing file or move processing file to processed after completion of the all router -->
    <exception-strategy ref="fot_exception_strategy_multiple" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>

<flow name="TesterFlow4" doc:name="TesterFlow4">
    <custom-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" class="com.XXX.XXX.service.AggregateResults" doc:name="Custom Aggregator"/>
    <component class="com.XXX.XXX.service.MoveProcessedFiles" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

I added a custom aggregator as shown below

```
public class AggregateResults extends AbstractAggregator{

@Override
protected EventCorrelatorCallback getCorrelatorCallback(MuleContext muleContext) {
     return new CollectionCorrelatorCallback(muleContext,false,storePrefix)
        {
         @Override
            public MuleEvent aggregateEvents(EventGroup events) throws AggregationException
            {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(128);

                try
                {
                    for (Iterator<MuleEvent> iterator = events.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
                    {
                        MuleEvent event = iterator.next();
                        try
                        {
                            buffer.append(event.transformMessageToString());
                        }
                        catch (TransformerException e)
                        {
                            throw new AggregationException(events, null, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (ObjectStoreException e)
                {
                    throw new AggregationException(events,null,e);
                }

                logger.debug("event payload is: " + buffer.toString());
                return new DefaultMuleEvent(new DefaultMuleMessage(buffer.toString(), muleContext), events.getMessageCollectionEvent());
            }
        };
}

}
```

Comment: If you use async, you need to dispatch the output of the 3 flows to another flow where an aggregator will assemble the result.

Comment: I tried this i landed up with a problem after the Aggregator where the original message and properties are getting lost. I need to retain the message properties after the aggregator. The aggregator is as below                                                                   public class AggregateResults extends AbstractAggregator{
    @Override
    protected EventCorrelatorCallback    getCorrelatorCallback(MuleContext muleContext) {              return new CollectionCorrelatorCallback(muleContext,false,storePrefix);}

Comment: @David can you gimme some pointers as to why the original message properties are getting lost after the aggregation. How can i retain the same in the aggregator

Comment: Are you using VM endpoints to tie things together? That could explain the loss of inbound properties.

Comment: They are not vm endpoints please see below the flow-ref "TesterFlow1"                 <sub-flow name="TesterFlow1" doc:name="TesterFlow1">
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="Destination_System" value="XXX"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\filelanding\out4\out1" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="output_4_1" doc:name="File"/>
    </sub-flow>

Comment: @David as you suggested i have dispatched the output of the three flows to another flow where i added the aggregator

Comment: TesterFlow4 has the aggregator. Please see the code snippet below <all doc:name="All">
            <async doc:name="Async">
                <flow-ref name="TesterFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            </async>
            <async doc:name="Async">
                <flow-ref name="TesterFlow3" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            </async>
            <async doc:name="Async">
                <flow-ref name="TesterFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            </async>
        </all>
        <flow-ref name="TesterFlow4" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the most recent config, chunks of XML in comments don't cut it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the flow configuration

Comment: Just to be sure: TesterFlow1, TesterFlow2 and TesterFlow3 end with a flow-ref towards TesterFlow4 so their results can be aggregated?

Comment: After the aggregator, the event message payload should be an instance of `org.mule.api.MuleMessageCollection`: you should be able to retrieve the message properties in each of the messages it contains.

Comment: The component in TesterFlow4 how should it get handle on the org.mule.api.MuleMessageCollection i was implementing Callable interface `public class MoveProcessedFiles implements Callable `.

Comment: Should be in the event message payload.

Comment: I had added a custom aggregator a shown above but the message properties are not available `MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();` but the message payload is contents of the file placed at the inbound endpoint and not the `org.mule.api.MuleMessageCollection`

Comment: within my aggregator i was trying to modify the payload after i fixed this the component after the aggregator receives a DefaultMessageCollection. Should i set the correlation size and id properties before the aggregator. I am not able to get this working could be because i am using async